# Plotly: How to show trendline for time series data using plotly express?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, regression

Using the built in "tips" dataframe in plotly express, I first create a datetime column.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_tips = px.data.tips()
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=df_tips.shape[0]).tolist()
df_tips['date'] = datelist
```

Using a column of datetimes as the x-axis gives the error:

```
px.scatter(df_tips,x='date',y='tip',trendline='ols')    
...
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

Using any other column does not. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Note: no error is present when the trendline argument is removed.

Comment: if you create the columns date with `df_tips['date'] = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=df_tips.shape[0]).astype('int64')` it works, is it what you look for?

Comment: Thanks. That does give a trendline, but the date axis is now in integer form

Comment: @stephenb How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

The safest approach is to run the regression on a serialized representation of your dates, and then set th x-axis up to be displayed as strings. By serialized representation I mean, for example, the approach suggested by Ben.T in his comment, or the one used in 
[Plot best fit line with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126989/plot-best-fit-line-with-plotly). Then you can set up the layout of the x-axis using:

```
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,
                 tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = df_tips['date'][0::40],
                 ticktext= [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in datelist[0::40]])
```

The `df_tips['date'][0::40]` part makes sure there's some space between each tickmark.

**Plot 1:**

[image]

This approach even works well if you'd like to make use of other dimensions of your dataset with, for example: `fig = px.scatter(df_tips,x='date',y='tip', color = 'sex', trendline='ols')`:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_tips = px.data.tips()
df_tips['date'] = df_tips.index
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=df_tips.shape[0]).tolist()

fig = px.scatter(df_tips,x='date',y='tip', trendline='ols')
fig = px.scatter(df_tips,x='date',y='tip', color = 'sex', trendline='ols')  

fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,
                 tickmode = 'array',
                 tickvals = df_tips['date'][0::40],
                 ticktext= [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in datelist])

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works and shows nice chart

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    "value": [6, 10, 15],
    "timestamp": ["2023-12-01 09:26:15", "2023-12-01 09:30:15", "2023-12-01 09:45:14"],
}

data["timestamp"] = np.array(data["timestamp"], dtype="datetime64")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a scatter plot with a trendline
fig = px.scatter(
    df, x="timestamp", y="value", trendline="ols", title="Trendline for Value over Time"
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```